# Can I merge h264 and aac to ts stream by code?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

There are one h264 stream and aac stream I received from USB devise, I need to merge them and output to one file, I can do it by ffmpeg by

```
FFMpeg: ffmpeg -i audio.au -i video.h264 -vcodec copy -acodec copy play.ts
```

I want to do this in my c code, which is one linux c application.

who can gave me some examples code or tip ?

Comment: What programming language of your code?

Comment: It is one linux c application.

Answer (score 1):

using C, IMHO the easiest way is 'system'.

```
   #include <studio.h>
   ..... 
   system("ffmpeg -i audio.au -i video.h264 -vcodec copy -acodec copy play.ts")
```

but take care to the ffmpeg license. because depending how your program use ffmpeg it may have huge implication!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIFO to achieve this. Write the two files into FIFO.